# Can't create Build Controller on other server for TFS

Tags: domain, team-foundation-server, build-server

I'm currently working on creating a test environment on my local machine using some virtual servers:

- TWITCH: This server contains the real TFS Server
- BUILDSERVER: This server should contain the Build Agent to be used by
  TFS
- SANDBOX: This server will be my Sandbox environment
- INTEGRATION: This server will be my Integration environment

However I'm currently running into an issue with creating the build controller on the BUILDSERVER. I have created an account on "TWITCH" named "TWITCH\BuildServer" that has administrator access on TFS.

When I now go to Build Configuration on the "BUILDSERVER" and try to connect to TFS I can see the project (after loging in with this TWITCH\BuildServer account. However when I now enter this account in the field "Connect to Team Foundation Server as:" I receive some errors:

First when I click "Test" I see the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V9MF.png

If I just ignore this message and click ok, followed by Start on the left window I receive another message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/44gSq.png

Does anyone have an idea how I can somehow connect these 2 servers? (I would prefer to not setup a domain controller if at all possible), if however this is the onl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well explained at [Managing Team Foundation Server in a Workgroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (can't find where this doc has moved in the newer version).

The general idea is that you need shadow accounts, so in your case you must create a BUILDSERVER\BuildServer account with the same password as TWITCH\BuildServer, and use the BUILDSERVER\BuildServer in the configuration dialog.